# Defining a directory for calling CPLEX within Python

Tags: python, cplex, opl

I want to run a .mod file written in the OPL language (CPLEX IDE) from Python. For this aim, I use the following commands:

```
from doopl.factory import *
with create_opl_model(model=model_file) as model_name:
    model_name.run()
```

But of course, at first, I need to open the file, which is named model_file, and also to define a directory for this. For this aim, in the beginning, I do as the following:

```
import os
from os.path import dirname, abspath, join
```

Now, my questions are:

**1.** I wonder if there is a need for `abspath, join`, or just like next is enough:

```
from os.path import dirname
```

**2.** I think I need to use the next commands to define the directory?

```
DATADIR = join(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

model_file = join(DATADIR, 'main.mod')
```

**But** where have I to write the directory? Instead of **file** or other place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoocallopl.py

```
from doopl.factory import *
# Data

Buses=[
        (40,500),
        (30,400)
        ]

# Create an OPL model from a .mod file
with create_opl_model(model="zootupleset.mod") as opl:
    # tuple can be a list of tuples, a pandas dataframe...
    opl.set_input("buses", Buses)

    # Generate the problem and solve it.
    opl.run()

    # Get the names of post processing tables
    print("Table names are: "+ str(opl.output_table_names))

    # Get all the post processing tables as dataframes.
    for name, table in iteritems(opl.report):
        print("Table : " + name)
    for t in table.itertuples(index=False):
            print(t)

    # nicer display
    for t in table.itertuples(index=False):
        print(t[0]," buses ",t[1], "seats")
```

I had the .mod and the python program in the same directory

But if the .mod is in the temp2 directory that is in the same directory as temp which contains the python program then I change

```
with create_opl_model(model="zootupleset.mod") as opl:
```

into

```
with create_opl_model(model="../temp2/zootupleset.mod") as opl:
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. @Alex Fleischer